# UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps always triggering every input value change

Tags: reactjs, antd

`UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` is always triggering for every input value change which is placed in the component itself.

As per my knowledge, it should be triggered only based on its props value change form the parent component.

Can someone help me with a hint, or please correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is wrong. Checking if props did change is what `nextProps` param is for. It's preferable to use other hooks, since this one is legacy and may result in undesirable behaviour. A preferable hook depends on your case. Consider explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops):

> Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies.

Use `componentDidUpdate` instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.someProp != prevProps.someProp) {
    // The property someProp changed
    // Do something in response
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps takes an argument like;

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(props){
 const {someprop} : this.props;
 if(someprop !== props.someprop){
 //do whatever you want with the refreshed someprop
 }
 }
```